# Question for a server specific question which will build a programming environment?

Tags: discussion

I am aware that there is serverfault and stackoverflow, each to their own specific role on the stack exchange servers.

On the chance I have a question which is server specific but includes some programming environment; where would a question like this belong?

Question is about using IIS to have a mapped module for two versions of PHP, which also consists of the ups and downsides of each of the server specific roles which IIS 7.0+ has to offer, like possible vulunerabilities and such.

Chances are if I post something relivent to a server configuration, I would be re-directed to serverfault;

But if I ask on Serverfault, chances are that my question will be redirected or even closed due to it's programming nature?

So which one would a question like so belong on? (by this, I mean a question specific to a server configuration for a programming environment?)

Comment: Serverfault, to my knowledge, does deal with some code when relevant to servers. After all, it's hard to run a server without code. That being said, it depends what the focus of your question is.

Comment: It depends... Is the question primarily a server question? Or is it primarily a programming question? If you believe there is a chance of misunderstanding - explain why you posted where you posted and why you believe that's the right place.

Comment: Question is about using IIS to have a mapped module for two versions of PHP, which also consists of the ups and downsides of each of the server specific roles which IIS 7.0+ has to offer, like possible vulunerabilities and such

Comment: So, no programming aspect. This is not a Stack Overflow question and looks fitting for Server Fault.

Comment: @DarylGill - at SF we don't really deal in speculation, so we're not going to give you a list of "ups and downsides" of particular configurations. We're also not going to do your research for you by providing you a list of vulerabilities. So it sounds like your SF question would be off-topic on all the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about setting up and configuring a server, so ServerFault would be the best fit. It doesn't matter if the server will be set up with programming environment, or some other environment. Either way, it's still setting up a server. It's not about the actual programming that will be done in this environment, so it's not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Consider the SO faq guidelines for appropriate questions:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers

The first two bullet points definitely don't apply to your question, and "tools" might tangentially apply, but that would be a stretch (I personally would consider it off topic). On the other hand, here are the ServerFault guidelines:

- Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization
- Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
- Network routing, switches, and firewalls
- Operations, maintenance, and monitoring

The first and last bullet points definitely apply to your question.

But in any case, avoid making requests for open-ended suggestions and opinions, as that is not constructive. "The ups and downsides of each of the server specific roles which IIS 7.0+ has to offer" has no definite answer and shouldn't be included as part of your question. Instead, try to come up with specific details about your requirements, and you can ask if IIS 7.0+ meets those.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring IIS to run two versions of PHP is something that [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) can help with. Though you may also want to include *why* you want to do this, as this can lead to a better answer or an alternative approach you hadn't considered.

However, the remainder of your proposed question is "not constructive" as it's asking for debate, opinion or discussion. You may want to have that conversation in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127) instead.

For reference, see also [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)